# Creating a NSArray from a C Array

Tags: objective-c, c, nsstring, nsarray

There are many threads about going the opposite way, but I am interested in converting from a primitive C array to a NSArray. The reason for this is that I want to create a NSString from the array contents. To create the NSString I will use:

```
NSArray *array;
NSString *stringFromArray = [array componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

I am joining the elements of the array by commas because I will later be saving the string as a .csv file. I don't think it matters, but the C array I am dealing with is of type double and size 43.

```
double c_array = new double [43];
```

Thanks!

Comment: There's no automatic boxing in ObjC even for primitive types, let alone arrays. So you won't be able to do that without a loop. But if you're coding a loop, you might as well do your string concatenation within that loop - no need to spend time and memory on building a NSArray first.

Comment: `double c_array = new double[43];` isn't any C array I've ever heard of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSString * stringFromArray = NULL;
NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 43];
if(array)
{
    NSInteger count = 0;

    while( count++ < 43 )
    {
        [array addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", c_array[count]]];
    }

    stringFromArray = [array componentsJoinedByString:@","];
    [array release];     
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! Only change I made was using a for loop instead of your while loop. The first count value was 1. I needed 0 to access the first element of c_array. Otherwise extremely helpful.